# Trying to obtain element from BeautifulSoup but might be blocked

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the coordinates on a graph that is listed in the HTML.

URL: "http://www.worldacd.com/index"

HTML:[image: HTML]

I got to as far as this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wacd_homepage = requests.get("http://www.worldacd.com/index")
wacd_homepage_soup = BeautifulSoup(wacd_homepage.content, "html.parser")

soup = wacd_homepage_soup.body.find("div", {"class":"container main"}).find("div", {"id":"content"}).find("div", {"class":"tab-content"}).find("div", {"class":"tab-pane active"}).find("div", {"class":"row"}).find("div",{"class":"span10"}).find("div",{"class":"wrapper"}).find("div",{"class":"chart"})
soup
```

The result would be just a one-liner:

```
<div class="chart" id="chart_index"></div>
```

Nothing else to see. Ultimately, I want to get to the segment as pointed out in the picture. Is the HTML partially blocked (not sure if i'm using the right terminology here)?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that "chart_index" element is used to google chart library.
You can find 860 line on source code of "http://www.worldacd.com/index"

```
chart_index = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_index'));
```

I think that you are able to retrieve the coordinates on a graph using parse JS.

for example,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wacd_homepage = requests.get("http://www.worldacd.com/index")
wacd_homepage_soup = BeautifulSoup(wacd_homepage.content, "html.parser")

soup = wacd_homepage_soup.find_all('script', {"type":"text/javascript"})
print(soup)
```

In contents of "soup", you can find the coordinates on a graph like "[new Date(2009, 1, 1), 98.55, 94.86, 96.25]" each "USD", "EUR" and "CNY".